# Why is there no border on this?

Tags: html, css

Pretty much explains it.  When you toggle invisible div there is no border around it, even though it's specified in CSS

**Snippet added below:**

```js
$("#button").click(function () {
    $(".hidden").slideToggle(200);
    });
```

```css
.hidden{
     background-color:#ccc;
     width:120px;
     text-decoration:none;
     font-size:14px;
     color:blue;
     display:none;
     border:thick;
     border:green;
     margin: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
     padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em; 
    }
    .style2 {
     border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    </head>    
    <body>
      <div class="hidden">woot</div>
    <table style="width: 25%" cellspacing="1" class="style2">
     <tr>
      <td class="style2" style="width: 182px"><p id="button"><a href="#">Toggle</a></p>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="style2">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: On a side note, `thick green solid` sounds wrong :P

Comment: On another side note, `margin: 1em` is shorthand for `margin: 1em 1em 1em 1em` (likewise for `padding`)

Answer (score 3):

Because you're overriding the `border` property by declaring it twice:

```
border:thick;
border:green;
```

The second decleration overrides the first. If you did:

```
border-style: solid;
border-color: green;
```

it would be working fine.

A neater solution is to combine the values into a single decleration:

```
border: 1px solid green;
```

Also your border style value 'thick' doesn't exist as far as the spec i'm reading states.

Values include: dotted, dashed, solid, double groove, ridge, inset & outset.

**Update**

I see now that the value 'thick' is meant for border-width in which case it is fine to use this value.

```
border-style: solid;
border-color: green;
border-width: thick;
```

or

```
border: thick solid green;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying the shorthand `border` twice. I suspect the bottom is overriding the top with a width of `0`.

Combine them:

```
border: thick green;
```

Or don't use the shorthand:

```
border-width: thick;
border-color: green;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
border: 1px solid green;
```

or the below three together

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: thick;
border-color: green;
```

Answer (score 1):

[`border`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) is a shorthand property -- it's the shorthand way of writing out:

```
border-width: thick;
border-style: solid;
border-color: green;
```

Try:

```
border: thick solid green;
```

Comment: And `thick` is a width, not a style, so `3px thick` is wrong.

Comment: You missed the part before "Try".

Comment: *Chuckles* -- moving to fast for my own good -- thanks again @BoltClock.

Comment: I fixed it further for you, you were mixing up the properties. Slow down! :)

Answer (score 1):

you are missing one Border Argument and you apply it wrong, try `border: thick solid green;` instead of:

```
border:thick;
border:green;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `border: think; border: green;` to `border: thick green solid;`. You need to define those three things to make borders show up.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get complicated.

```
border: 5px solid #000;
```

Comment: It's best if you just use all of the information in the one section of style.